# How can I get the correct size of my UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiview

**Question 1:**

How do I get the correct size of a UIView?

I am creating a CGRect to show some images using tiled layers.
When I'm creating the CGRect, I basically need it to be the exact same size as that of my UIView. This turned out to be quite hard..
When I NSLog() out my `mainView.bounds.size.width` or my `mainView.frame.size.width` they are always wrong when in landscape! They always log out the values as if it was in portrait, even though I can see the actual view being wider. And reversing them will also be wrong. 
It's not good enough set the width to be the height and vice versa when in landscape, I need the right values.

The only way I've been able to make it look right is to manually put in 1024 for width when in Landscape, and this doesn't always work either, because:

**Question 2:**

What is the correct way to check if the device is in landscape or not?

I've been using

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```

but this doesn't always work. If I hold my device in landscape mode when launching, it is correct, but if I make it landscape, then lay the iPad flat down leaving the dashboard as landscape and THEN launch it, then the landscape-splash shows up, but that code think it's in portrait.
That code doesn't work at all for iPad simulator either..

**EDIT**

For some reason, when I decided to add support for landscape orientation, it wasn't enough to just check the landscape-orientations in the summary-page of the target, I had to actually sub-class my TabBarController and physically tell it to rotate with

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

I shouldn't have to do this.. right? If I create an empty project like that, it doesn't need it.. I don't know why.

Comment: I remember having issues just like this when I put a tab bar controller inside of a navigation controller (an unsupported configuration which Apple says not to implement).  Any chance that's what you are doing?

Comment: @lnafziger No, but at some points I have navigationControllers inside the tabBarController, but that shouldn't be the problem either..

Comment: Yeah, that's perfectly acceptable....  Perhaps you can upload your app, or even better a small version of your app that showcases this behavior so that we can look into it a little more closely.

Comment: @lnafziger I don't feel comfortable uploading the entire app, so I'd have to reproduce the situation with a new project, but I don't have time today, maybe later if I'm not satisfied with the current quick-fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
Yup, that's right.  :)

Question 2: 
I just got home and checked my own code.  I use:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

to check the orientation of the current interface.  Then, you can use something like:

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    // Do something
} else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    // Do something else
}
```

**HOWEVER** You really should not need to do this if you properly handle rotation events.

Here is my typical way of dealing with rotation when I need to adjust UI element positions in code based on orientation:

```
#pragma mark - View rotation methods

// Maintain pre-iOS 6 support:
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

// Make sure that our subviews get moved on launch:
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self moveSubviewsToOrientation:orientation duration:0.0];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [self moveSubviewsToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

// Animate the movements
- (void)moveSubviewsToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                     animations:^{
                         [self.tableView reloadData];
                         if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
                         {
                             [self moveSubviewsToPortrait];
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             [self moveSubviewsToLandscape];
                         }
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}

- (void)moveSubviewsToPortrait
{
    // Set the frames/etc for portrait presentation
    self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(229.0, 21.0, 309.0, 55.0);
}

- (void)moveSubviewsToLandscape
{
    // Set the frames/etc for landscape presentation
    self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(88.0, 21.0, 309.0, 55.0);
}
```

I also put `moveSubviewsToOrientation` in `viewWillAppear` to have it rotate

Comment: Basically it gets called from viewDidLoad, but when I start the app in landscape, wouldn't this not matter? Or will the app always load the view as portrait?

Comment: and `self.interfaceOrientation` apparently does the same thing. When launching from flat down landscape, it still figures it's portrait..

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was guessing. From my experience, the frame/bounds is not yet set in viewDidLoad.  Try moving it like I suggested and see what you get.  The interface probably hasn't rotated yet either (a view controller always launches in portrait and then rotates to landscape).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was what he meant. Anyway, none of this worked for me.. The self.interfaceOrientation always thought it was in portrait, even though I held it in landscape. I put the whole viewDidLoad into viewWillAppear just to be sure, and nothing changed..

Comment: I see how it should work, but it still doesn't.. :( 
I have now tried calling `if(UIDeviceInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])){NSLog(@"Landscape");}else{NSLog(@"Portrait");}`, and it prints out "Portrait" even though the statusbar is in landscape. The statusbar is in landscape even before I launch the application, and it still thinks it's in portrait.. I've tried several methods with the same result, my device shows in landscape, but the variables returns portrait.. I don't know what to do.

Comment: If I moved it to `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` it worked, but at the cost of a tiny second without any content on the screen, based on how fast the device is I guess. It'll have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a bit and here are some facts I found:

1- When a device is face up or down, the device reverts to the last orientation prior to it being face up or down since those 2 orientations do not tell you necessarily on their own whether the device is portrait or landscape. So for example, if you were in landscape and then put the device flat face up, then launch an app, it will launch in the landscape orientation.

2- When viewDidLoad is called, the bounds have not been set, so you need to put any calls that pertain to the orientation in viewWillAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews.

3- If for some odd reason, you need to use the bounds before viewDidLoad, or maybe to do something in a model, I have found that the best way to put settings that pertain to the orientation is to trust the statusbar, which you can call as follows for example.

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
```

PS: Regarding your added question, refer to:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html

You are most likely one of the last 2 bullets. I ran into this issue before and quite frankly found it easiest to just implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

for all VCs just to be on the safe side especially that the behaviour has changed from iOS5 to iOS6.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1

Hope this helps

Comment: Hm, now I'm starting to think there's something wrong with my device or my code.. This line of code didn't work at all.. It always says it is portrait here..

Comment: Reading back your question, I have not tested my comments in simulator mode (regarding your ipad comment). On the other hand, when you say this line of code does not work, do you mean in viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear? Also make sure to call super in these methods.

Comment: I still think there's something wrong somewhere. This was originally just an iPhone app, now I'm adding iPad-support, and I'd like landscape for it. Now I only have a TabBar with one single UIView connected to it. I have subclassed the TabBarController, added shouldAutorotate..:YES to both of them, and it DOES rotate, but all the different if-statements returns portrait if it LAUNCHES in landscape. If I add code in didAutorotate (or whatever it's called) it get's it right. The problem is that when launching in landscape, I get this huge white gap on the right of my screen as if portrait..

Comment: Did you see my comment below where I said that the interface always launches in portrait and then rotates to landscape (when you are in landscape mode)?  As long as you properly implement them both, it doesn't matter what it launches in as long as you call the appropriate methods in viewDidRotate to update for the appropriate orientation...

Comment: @Inafziger. Interesting. it seems correct for iphone but not for iPad; iPad always launches in the last status bar orientation. Again I am not using simulator.

Comment: Yeah, I just did a test on the iPad and it seems that you are correct.

Comment: @lnafziger That's weird, I have been using iPad all along and it still thinks it's in portrait, even if the landscape-splash is showing and the statusbar is right.. There has to be something I have overridden or ruined while coding.. Anyway, I solved the problem by putting everything in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`, with the cost of a tiny second of nothingness, but that'll do for now.